# Better to Have Script Loop or Run in Task Scheduler

Tags: python, loops, scheduled-tasks

Let's say I have a simple python script:

```
import os
x = os.listdir(path)
xO = open(file, 'a')
xO.write(x)
xO.close()
```

This is just an example, but I do have a short easy script similar to this. I need this script to run every 5 minutes. I've found that doing something like this can eat a lot of resources over time:

```
import os
import time
while true:
    x = os.listdir(path)
    xO = open(file, 'a')
    xO.write(x)
    xO.close()
    time.sleep(300)
```

So would it be easier on my PC to have the script called every 5 minutes by Windows Task Scheduler? Or is there another solution I don't know about.

Comment: The answer is in the question... That's what schedulers are for.

Comment: Agree with @brunodesthuilliers.

Comment: The Task Scheduler is a OS service running all the time anyway, so by utilizing it alone instead of it _and_ your script "runner" probably requires less computer resources overall. However, it may require more coding on your part to set up the needed scheduled task (and perhaps also cancel it later).

Answer (score 0):

No one wanted to answer, but @brunodesthuilliers had it. Use Task Scheduler, that's what schedulers are for.